# How do I move a header down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get a header to move in a 200 by 200-pixel square, but my code is not working. I was going to use the topOffset and setInterval method to move the header, but I don't understand how topOffset works. So far my code only moves the header right 200 pixels:

```js
var leftOffset = 0;

        var moveRight = function () {
            $("#heading").offset({left:leftOffset});

            leftOffset++;

            if (leftOffset > 200) {
                leftOffset = 200;
            }
        };

        setInterval(moveRight, 4);

        var offsetTop = 0;
        var moveDown = function () {
            $("#heading").offset({down:offsetTop});

            offsetTop--;

            if(offsetTop < 200) {
                offsetTop = 200;
            }
        };

        setInterval(moveDown,4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id = "heading">Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: What are you reffering to as "topOffset" ?

Comment: Keep in mind your logic for `moveDown` is setting the `down` to 0, decrement it, check if -1 is less than 200 (it is), and set it to 200.  Then next iteration it will set it to 200, decrement it, check if 199 is less than 200 (it is), and set it to 200.  Then it will set it to 200, decrement it, check if 199 ...

Answer (score 2):

For animation like this you are much better off using CSS, not JS. For starters it performs *much* better due to CSS being hardware-accelerated. It's also much simpler to implement and works even if someone has JS disabled in their browser.

In your case you can use keyframe animation to set the position of the element at each stage. Try the below example. Note that I used 150px instead of 200px only so that the effect is easier to see in the snippet. You can easily change the `top` and `left` values to anything you need.

```css
@keyframes square {
  0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
  25% { top: 0; left: 150px; }
  50% { top: 150px; left: 150px; }
  75% { top: 150px; left: 0; }
  100% { top: 0; left: 0; }
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: square;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading">Hello World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function to:

```js
var moveDown = function () {
    $("#heading").offset({top:offsetTop});

    offsetTop++;

    if(offsetTop > 200) {
        offsetTop = 200;
    }
};
```

That should give you your desired effect.

Comment: If I increase the offset top does that mean that the header gets farther away from the top of the console? If offsetTop is decreased does the header get closer?

Comment: Correct. The higher you set the limit, currently 200, the further down it will go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "down" listed as a possible coordinate for offset in jQuery's documentation, try "top" instead, that should be the only update needed.

```js
var leftOffset = 0;

var moveRight = function() {
  $("#heading").offset({
    left: leftOffset
  });

  leftOffset++;

  if (leftOffset > 200) {
    leftOffset = 200;
  }
};

setInterval(moveRight, 4);

var offsetTop = 0;
var moveDown = function() {
  $("#heading").offset({
    top: offsetTop
  });

  offsetTop--;

  if (offsetTop < 200) {
    offsetTop = 200;
  }
};

setInterval(moveDown, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading">Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: This code actually doesn't work the way I want it too. This makes the heading move diagonally down instead of right and then down. You need to create an if statement saying that IF the leftOffset=200 THEN offsetTop--; This way both functions don't run at the same time. Also, in order for the header to move down, the topOffset is increased and not decreased because the topOffset is the distance away from the top of the screen.